# Comparing two Integers with my own Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I am learning how to use Comparator interface in java and I am trying to write my own Comparator which would compare Integers differently ( e.g 3>5 ). I have a problem with it, could someone tell what is wrong with my code?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class MyComparator<Integer> implements Comparator<Integer>
{
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b)
    {
        if(a.compareTo(b)>0)
        return -1;
        else if(a.compareTo(b)<0)
            return 1; 
        else 
            return 0;
    }
}
```

The compilator cannot find compareTo(Integer).

Comment: I would also like to point out that you can simply write `return b.compareTo(a);`

Comment: Have a look at `Integer.compare(int, int)`

Comment: so it is the same as `return -a.compareTo(b);` or `return b.compareTo(a);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
class MyComparator<Integer> implements Comparator<Integer>
```

to

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer>
```

In the first case you're declaring a [type parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) which is shadowing `java.lang.Integer`.