# Shadowing of type parameters

Tags: java

I have a very basic question regarding type parameters which I came across while solving a problem.

I have a class with a string array which I am sorting using a custom Comparator class. Below is my Comparator class

```
class SortComparator implements Comparator<String>
    {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return  o1.compareTo(o2);
        }

    }
```

The above class runs fine and outputs the desired result.

If the class name is changed from `SortComparator` to `SortComparator<String>` the compare method needs to be changed. The class after changes looks like this

```
class SortComparator<String> implements Comparator<String>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  ((java.lang.String) o1).compareTo((java.lang.String) o2);
    }

}
```

The above class also runs fine and outputs the desired result

**Why is there a need to explicitly cast the `String` objects `o1` and `o2` to `java.lang.String` when they already are objects of the same class?**

I searched for this query of mine for some time on net and found a very similar question

[Comparing two Integers with my own Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610170/comparing-two-integers-with-my-own-comparator)

The answer to this question says that it is because of `shadowing`.

I know shadowing in terms of local variables, instance variables and class variables but how does it work in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with generic type that is called `String`. It's collision between generic type parameter and actual class `String`.

Because the type parameter `String` is **unbounded**, the Java compiler replaces it with `Object` hence arguments of method `compare` works as `Object` and object class doesn't have `compareTo` method hence you have to cast.

Try below example that works fine.

```
class SortComparator<T> implements Comparator<String>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  o1.compareTo(o2);
    }

}
```

Please have a look at Java documentation on [Erasure of Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)

> During the type erasure process, the Java compiler erases all type parameters and replaces each with its first bound if the type parameter is bounded, or Object if the type parameter is unbounded.

Below Example copied directly from above Java documentation for more clarity.

Consider the following generic class that represents a node in a singly linked list:

```
public class Node<T> {

    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;

    public Node(T data, Node<T> next) }
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getData() { return data; }
    // ...
}
```

Because the type parameter T is unbounded, the Java compiler replaces it with Object:

```
public class Node {

    private Object data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(Object data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Object getData() { return data; }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Good explanation and good link. Do you mind explaining the meaning of `first bound class` in the link provided? Especially this: `The Java compiler replaces the bounded type parameter T with the first bound class, Comparable:`. How does it relate to this `public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>`? Comparable is the superclass, how can it be the first bound? Or was it referring to T as first bound?

Comment: Here 'T' is bounded to any class that extends Comparable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `Here 'T' is bounded to any class that extends Comparable.`, that i understand. But what i don't is, what is "first bound" ? Thanks.